# how to set link on my image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set hyperlink on the biggest circle area in my image.

I try to use map tag.

I try to set absolute position coords on area tag and it work fine when I click it on my browser in PC.

But the absolute position is wrong on my android's browser.

Hence, I try to use div tag to get my link.

But I didn't find my green area for clicking.

My code as below link

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer{
        background:orange;
    }
    #inner{
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        top:10%;
        right:10%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        background:green;
    }
</style>

<div id=outer>
  <div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KuxMbSoKHsl1MXQUi2nmrOcSpCWN_WaRsL7Q1WatODA/pub?w=960&amp;h=720" height="100%" width="100%"  />
  </div>
  <div id=inner> 
      <a href="https://www.google.com"></a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check out https://jsfiddle.net/hL09ses6/1/ for more.

Comment: Link is not for whole image. I hope It just for the biggest circle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your image as a **`hyperlink`** to another page:

- by wrapping it inside an anchor tag **`<a>`** &
- by setting its **`href`** attribute to the **`url`** of the page you want the browser to navigate to.

**Code:**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KuxMbSoKHsl1MXQUi2nmrOcSpCWN_WaRsL7Q1WatODA/pub?w=960&amp;h=720"height="100%" width="100%"  />
</a>
```

---

**Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL09ses6/3/) for more.**
**In the following snippet you can see your own code working:**

```css
#outer {
  background: orange;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 10.5%;
  right: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

#bigcircle {
  /* The numbers may require slight adjustments */
  width: 21.6%;
  height: 36%;
  top: 1.6%;
  right: 22.8%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id=outer>
  <div>
    <img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KuxMbSoKHsl1MXQUi2nmrOcSpCWN_WaRsL7Q1WatODA/pub?w=960&amp;h=720" height="100%" width="100%" />
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <div id="bigcircle"></div>
  </a>
  <div id=inner>
    <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**For more advanced uses I suggest that image mapping is used! Find out more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp).**

Comment: Not for whole image. I hope It just for the biggest circle

Comment: Try clicking the big circle now.

Comment: I try to use your code in my blogger. But its position is wrong.Could I fixed it?http://chenweilun.blogspot.tw/

Comment: I had try it before posting this article.I had update to my blog. The below image is using image mapping.But the absolute position is wrong on my android's browser.

Comment: you can try to click the Top-right corner for the below image on my blog.

Comment: Glad I could help @weilun

Answer (score 0):

Your demo is [here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks07.htm)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
An image that is a link:
<a href="https://www.google.com">
<img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KuxMbSoKHsl1MXQUi2nmrOcSpCWN_WaRsL7Q1WatODA/pub?w=960&amp;h=720" height="100%" width="100%"  />
</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not for whole image. I hope It just for the biggest circle

Comment: do you mean click is only on particular image part ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `img` tag between anchor tag.

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KuxMbSoKHsl1MXQUi2nmrOcSpCWN_WaRsL7Q1WatODA/pub?w=960&amp;h=720" height="100%" width="100%"  />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: why downvote? can that person tell me about downvote ?

Comment: Not for whole image. I hope It just for the biggest circle

Comment: you mean biggest circle in above image ?